# Find the same values in array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create a function that return true if I find 5 items of the same value.

My array: `['d', 'd', 's, 'c', 'h', 's']`

For example, if I find 5 times `'d'`, I want to return true. The same goes for `'h'`, `'s'` or `'c'`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `array.count('d') == 5`

Comment: Thanks! So simple yet powerfull